# how get value and text of select using select2 jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i use select2 jquery to select or add a state if it doesn't exist all this works fine, now i want to get the value of a state in console, in my example 1 for california or 2 for virginia.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#state").select2({
      tags: true
    });
    $("#btn-add-state").on("click", function(){
      var newStateVal = $("#new-state").val();
      // Set the value, creating a new option if necessary
      if ($("#state").find("option[value='" + newStateVal + "']").length) {
        $("#state").val(newStateVal).trigger("change");
        console.log($("#state").val());
      } else { 
        // Create the DOM option that is pre-selected by default
        var newState = new Option(newStateVal, newStateVal, true, true);
        // Append it to the select
        $("#state").append(newState).trigger('change');
        console.log($("#state").val());
      } 
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <h2>Dynamic autocomplete search and add using select2 JS </h2>
  <br/>
  <select id="state" class="js-example-basic-single" type="text" style="width:90%">
   <option value="1">California</option>
   <option value="2">Virginie</option>
  </select>
  <button  class="form-control btn btn-primary btn-add-state">ajouter item</button>
```

Comment: you want to get value and text from all options of select tag?

Comment: @Frenchy thx for u answer i want select tag

Comment: i dont understant what you mean...by "i want select tag" you dont really answer to my first question

Comment: Is this for a classroom assignment? Someone else just posted a question with this *exact* piece of code and worded slightly differently